# How can Nautilus dropdown and popup notifications be disabled?

Tags: nautilus, files, 16.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 and am using Nautilus 3.20.3. I find that Nautilus has changed such that actions like deletions and moves result in dropdown and popup notifications that obscure the current directory view. An example is shown below:

[image]

How can these notifications be disabled or otherwise changed so that they do not obscure things?